# Addition of exponential regression models to scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, scatter-plot

I have data set consisting of 7 species wet weights and size measurements. Number of observations range between 3 and 18 per species.

`Species   ID   Wet weight(g)   Size(mm)`

These measurements are visualised in a ggplot scatter plot. I used the following code.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("tidyverse")

p<-ggplot(Wet,aes(x=Size,y=WW,colour=Species))+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  labs(x="\nDiameter or Length (mm)",y="Wet weight (g)\n")+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=14,colour="black"),
        axis.title.y=element_text(size=18),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=14,colour="black"),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        legend.position="right",
        legend.text=element_text(colour="black",size=14),
        legend.title=element_blank())
p
```

I would like to add exponential regression models for every species and am interested in their equations, correlations coefficients and p-values.

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to add these to my scatter plot.

Thanks so much!!!

```
Species   ID   Wet Size (mm)   weight(g)
Aequorea   1   195   390
Aequorea   2   225   579
Aequorea   3   224   303
Aurelia   4   235   647
Aurelia   5   170   335
Aurelia   6   155   269
Cyanea   7   370   1499
Cyanea   8   460   5000
Cyanea   9   430   2011
...
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of your data.

Comment: And I just took a quick look at your records. It seems like you never accepted any answers in the past. Do you have a particularly high standard to consider an answer as helpful or qualified? This may affect if people want to post a new answer or not.

Comment: In my opinion, if you add seven (!) sets equations, correlations, coefficients, and p-values to the plot it will visually be too busy to be useful. That much text is better placed in an associated table.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I was not planning to include all of the equations etc. in the plot, but only the regression lines. Equations etc. should be best presented in a subsequent table or so.

Comment: A google search for "ggplot2 multiple regression lines" (without the quotes) turned up several references on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

Your example data frame contains only three data points for each species, which is a very small sample size to fit an exponential regression. As a result, I decided to add more data points to your example as follows.

```
Wet <- read.table(text = "Species Size   WW
Aequorea   195   390
Aequorea   225   579
Aequorea   224   303
Aequorea   280  1600
Aequorea   320  4000
Aurelia   235   647
Aurelia   170   335
Aurelia   155   269
Aurelia   300   2000
Aurelia   350   4500
Cyanea  370   1499
Cyanea  460   5000
Cyanea  430   2011
Cyanea  100   500
Cyanea  120   550
Cyanea  200  1000",
                  header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

We can use `geom_smooth` to fit non-linear regression to each species as follows. The `geom_smooth` code is only for plotting. You will need to use the `nls` function to find out the coefficients for each species.

```
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(Wet, aes(x = Size, y = WW, colour = Species))+
  geom_point(size=3)+
  labs(x = "\nDiameter or Length (mm)", y="Wet weight (g)\n")+
  geom_smooth(method = "nls",
              formula = y ~ a + x^b,
              method.args = list(start = c(a = 1, b = 1)),
              se = FALSE) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black"),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 18),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 14, colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "right",
        legend.text = element_text(colour = "black", size = 14),
        legend.title = element_blank())
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your helpful comment! I have implemented it into my code, but it dispays a warning:

Comment: Warning message:
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
number of iterations exceeded maximum of 50

Comment: The regression lines are not displayed in my version. What could be the reason?

Comment: Perhaps increase the number of `maxiter`: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-June/107606.html